# deno testing embedded tests in application code: why not?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, deno

I tried something today, and I'm not seeing enough downsides to not do this.

```
import {
  verify,
  create,
  getNumericDate,
} from "https://deno.land/x/djwt@v2.2/mod.ts";
import { User } from "./models.ts";
import { getUser } from "./controllers/users.ts";
import * as bcrypt from "https://deno.land/x/bcrypt@v0.2.4/mod.ts";

const key = "some-secret-jey";

const header = { alg: "HS512", typ: "JWT" };

const payload = {
  iss: "ted",
  exp: getNumericDate(60 * 60),
};

export async function authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
  const user: User = await getUser(username);
  if (await passMatch(password, user.hash)) {
    return await genToken();
  }
}

async function passMatch(password: string, hash: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return await bcrypt.compare(password, hash);
}

async function genToken(): Promise<string> {
  const jwt = await create(
    { alg: "HS512", typ: "JWT" },
    { foo: "bar" },
    "secret"
  );

  return jwt;
}

// ****************************************************************
// TESTS
// ****************************************************************
import {
  assertEquals,
  assert,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.90.0/testing/asserts.ts";

Deno.test("authenticate", async () => {
  const token = await authenticate("joe", "test1.d");
  assert(token);
});

Deno.test("passMatch", async () => {
  const password = "password";
  const hash = await bcrypt.hash(password);

  assert(await passMatch(password, hash));
});

Deno.test("genToken", async () => {
  assert(await genToken());
});
```

This is working in isolation, and i know `deno test` clearly expects the tests to be externalize, and I understand having clean code.
But doesn't this solve other problems like having tons of files auth.ts auth_test.ts ect, developer ease, less mocking and injection etc...

What are the long term consequences of continuing like this with just straight unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some using i found a reason to not do it, beyond it wasn't the design.

if i have `server.ts` importing `user.ts` then when i ran server tests, it would run user tests too.

i have abandoned this thought experiment